# Rails slow responce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app. But in my logs I have some strange output, especially string

```
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 45.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

45ms(views) + 3ms(AR) = 48ms but not 113

My app should be 2x faster. What is the problem?

Here is [full log](https://raw.github.com/gist/3782419/c1e3c15506e159acb3321b80086026be5827c504/log) for a single request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere it is said that your `113ms` should be the sum of whatever is inside the parenthesis. The time took by rails to handle the request is not there, nor is the time took by the logic in your action.

Comment: Then how can I find slow places? I have installed newrelic for my app. And the diagram at newrelic says that 90% of time goes to Ruby and 10% - to MySQL and Memcached. But if I'll take time for rendering from this 90% - what is left? Middlewares? Routing? Time for creating objects?

Comment: I never had a need for that much optimization, but I'd start with what newrelic tells me, and check [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html) to see if there is nothing in there that can be of use.